# How do I save a custom jave object in Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My custom object consists of an image and 3 strings (I have getters, setters, and constructors (empty included).

I am working on a google play clone, so this object is basically the card view of an app (-description). I have a nested recycler view (just like google play).

I want to be able to store with Firebase Storage those objects and add new ones inside a specific fragment and load them all in the home fragment. 
I am not sure how to do with the categories, store the apps in folders where the name of the folder is the category, or have a field to save the category, still not sure.

Anyways, now, I simply want to be able to save a custom object with Firebase Storage. Found guides working with Realtime Database but with Storage, not that many.

This is how my upload fragment looks so far:

```
public class AddAppFragment extends Fragment {

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;

    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;

    private EditText et_appName;
    private EditText et_appDescription;
    private TextView tv_addPhoto;
    private ImageView appImg;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_app, container, false);

        et_appDescription = v.findViewById(R.id.addApp_editText_appDescription);
        et_appName = v.findViewById(R.id.addApp_editText_appName);
        appImg = v.findViewById(R.id.addApp_imageView_appImg);
        tv_addPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.addApp_textView_addPhotoText);

        tv_addPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        String category = "favorites";
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        AppModel appModel = new AppModel(R.drawable.img1, et_appName.getText().toString().trim(), "5stars", et_appDescription.getText().toString());
        //StorageReference appRef = mStorageRef.child("apps").child(category). ????
        //                                                                     setValue not working (that is for RealTimeDB I think


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            appImg.setImageURI(imageUri);
            appImg.bringToFront();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide some data (ultimately, a sequence of bytes) that describes your object.  This is something you will have to figure out for yourself.  The Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK won't do this for you.

Comment: It's most common to store structure data in the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firebase, and only use Cloud Storage for storing unstructured files, such as images.